# Get useful information about a JIRA board using the REST API

Tags: rest, jira, dashing

I've been digging around documentation for JIRA's latest REST API (6.0.1) to try and dig out information about a particular dashboard (I'm playing around with [Dashing](http://shopify.github.io/dashing/) to create a widget displaying the number of open issues in a particular sprint). According to this:

https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/jira/6.0.1.html

jira.com/rest/api/2/dashboard/11311 will only give me something like:

```
{
  "id": "11311",
  "name": "blah",
  "self": "jira.com\/rest\/api\/2\/dashboard\/11311",
  "view": "jira.com\/secure\/Dashboard.jspa?selectPageId=11311"
}
```

which doesn't exactly give me a lot of information.

In greenhopper times, we could get more useful information with something like:

```
/rest/greenhopper/1.0/xboard/work/allData.json?rapidViewId=#{board_id}"
```

(Taken from [here](https://github.com/capncodewash/kandash/blob/master/jobs/jira_wip.rb)) but that seems to not work now..Any ideas if there's another endpoint which might return more information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it via a jql query. '914' is the agile board ID (a neat way to find this is  checking the last digits of the 'Report' URL of the board)

```
SCHEDULER.every '5s', :first_in => 0 do |job|
 uri = URI.parse(jira_url)
 http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
 req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/rest/api/2/search?jql=sprint%20%3D%20914%20AND%20status%20%3D%20%27In%20Progress%27")
 req.basic_auth username, password
 response = http.request(req)
 issuesinProgress = JSON.parse(response.body)["total"]  
 send_event('buzzwords', value: issuesinProgress)
end
```

[This](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) is a very useful tool to encode your query into urlencode.

```
sprint = 914 AND status = 'In Progress' encodes to sprint%20%3D%20914%20AND%20status%20%3D%20%27In%20Progress%27
```

Answer (score 0):

The jira-python source code has some examples of using the JIRA Agile REST API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up using jql, posted my answer.